# Why won't this script append a child div element?

Tags: javascript

When I click on the p element with an onclick attribute calling the make_child function I would expect it to append a div element when ever it is clicked but it seams to be only appending a text node to the paragraph element what is the cause of this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function make_child(text, id, type) {
    var text = document.createTextNode(text);
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    var add = document.createElement(type);
    var addtext = add.appendChild(text);
    target.appendChild(addtext);
}
</script>

 <p id="changeme" onclick="make_child('I have changed', 'changeme', 'div')">Click me to change</p>
```

Comment: What is your error console saying? I'm pretty sure it's saying something.

Comment: Well It was given me an invalid syntax error at the var text assignment so I changed that variable to text_a and now I have no errors, but it's still just append the textnode instead of the element with the text node in the element..

Comment: ah, I'm sorry, I overlooked that `text` is a text node.

Comment: where is your `changeme` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `target.appendChild(add)` instead of `target.appendChild(addtext)`

Edit (more detail):
The syntax for `appendChild` (from MDN) is:

```
var child = element.appendChild(child);
```

Where `child` is the element **being appended**. In this case, `addtext = add.appendChild(text)` is set to `text` rather than `add`. Just doing `target.appendChild(add)` should solve this problem.

This also means the variable `addtext` is useless; you can remove it leaving only

```
add.appendChild(text)
```

for that line.

Comment: How is the add variable appending the the text node being passed to the function?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. `add` is a reference to the html element to which you append stuff. When you call `add.appendChild(text)`, `add` itself changes. This means that, when you pass it to `target.appendChild`, you're passing the newly changed version which contains the added node.

Comment: But when does the textnode that is created get appended to the div element created?

Comment: The line `addtext = add.appendChild(text)`. This line actually does _two_ things: it sets `addtext` to `text` _and_ appends `text` to `add`. Basically, a side-effect of `add.appendChild(text)` is that `text` is appended to `add`, regardless of the assignment (`addtext = ...`).

Comment: Thank you I now understand, so it will still append the child even if I don't assign it to a variable.

Comment: Exactly. If you find this somewhat unintuitive, check out functional programming: in a functional program, there are no side-effects like this.

Comment: Regarding the above code am I correct in saying that is Object-Oriented code?

Comment: Basically, yes: you are, after all, using the Document **Object** Model (DOM).

Answer (score 2):

change the last line to this

```
target.appendChild(add);
```

now you are appending to the correct element

Comment: How is the add variable appending the the text node being passed to the function?

Comment: you created `add` as a div, and appended your text to it, now get your target and append the `add` div to it. I had no idea how your code was working before

Comment: apparently appendChild() returns the content of what was appended. i didnt know that before.