# how to add element within an element in html

Tags: javascript

i need to add a element div and within that div i need to add a label element how to do that.....??

```
var dd=document.getElementById("sample");
var d=document.createElement("div");
d.id="s";
d.innerHTML="welcome"
dd.appendChild(d);
var e=document.createElement("label");
e.innerHTML="success";
var f=dd.getElementById("div");
f.appendChild(e);
```

i have a div element sample in html..`<div id="sample"></div>` within that div element i add another div element with id "s" then i need to a label within the div id="s" how to do that????????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't this script append a child div element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924420/why-wont-this-script-append-a-child-div-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.

```
var dd = document.getElementById("sample");

var d=document.createElement("div");
d.id = "s";
d.innerHTML="welcome"

var e = document.createElement("label");
e.innerHTML="success";

dd.appendChild(d);
d.appendChild(e);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FzhYz/

Comment: a problem http://jsfiddle.net/saravanabalaji/XHV7X/3/  . look at this. when we click "gaming" then "os" a textbox will appear. when we again click os the textbox will disappear. but the problem is when we again click the browser the os and textbox must disappear but os alone disappear.. suggestion ...........

Answer (score 0):

```
d.appendChild(e);
```

Note that HTMLElementNodes do not have a getElementById method.

Answer (score 0):

```
dd.appendChild(d).appendChild(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dd = document.getElementById("sample");
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.id = "s";
d.innerHTML = "welcome"
var e = document.createElement("label");
e.innerHTML = "success";
d.appendChild(e);
dd.appendChild(d);
```